# In Tile coordinates, how to get one zoom-level deeper but span the same area?

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, zoom, mathematics

For an arbitrary tile region defined by `(z1, x1, y1)`, how can we increase `z1` to `z1 + 1` but span the exact area defined by `(z1, x1, y1)`?

For example, consider [t1=(2,2,1)](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/2/2/1.png). If we want zoom=3 for the same region, what (x,y) coordinates should we fetch and glue together?

Here is what I tried:

- `target=(latitude, longitude)`, `zoom = z1`
- convert target to `(x1, y1)`
- fetch tile: `t1 = (z1, x1, y1)` → (desired target area)
- `z2 = z1 + 1` → (desired zoom-level (detail level))
- convert `target` in (lat/long) with `z2` to get `(x2,y2)`: `t2 = (z2, x2, y2)`
- fetch `8` tiles in the neighborhood of `t2`, (like `(z2, x2 ± 1, y2 ± 1)`)
- assemble these 9 tiles together:

```
n1-n2-n3
n4-t2-n5
n6-n7-n8
```

But this solution does NOT span the same area as `t1`
Example: target=Berlin, [z1=2 (one tile)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7txI.png), [z2=3 (nine tiles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWLFA.png)

Comment: You can't do this solely with formula, since it would defy the principle of tile pyramid. You have to take into account also tile size. Standard tile size is square of `256px`. To achieve what you want in practical life, for example in Leaflet, you offset zoom levels by `-1` with tile layer `zoomOffset: -1` option and set tile size to `512px` with tile layer `tileSize: 512` option. Equivalent in OpenLayers would be to set tile size to `512px`, but divide resolutions for all zoom levels by `2`.